# Gulp Outputs Jibberish Error when Compiling SASS on Windows 10

Tags: windows, sass, console, gulp, windows-10

I'm using the gulp-ruby-sass module to compile my SCSS files. On my Mac the gulp task works fine. However, I cannot get my Windows 10 machine to do the same job, as it keeps throwing an error with broken encoding, so I cannot even read ang google it properly.

[19:22:55] Starting 'sass'...
[19:22:55] "sass" �� ����� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� �������� 䠩���.
[19:22:55] Finished 'sass' after 38 ms

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Check the file encoding .. My guess is that one is UTF8 and the other is something else.

Comment: I've double-checked the .scss file's encoding is UTF8, still the error is thrown ;(

Comment: Can you post your  gulpfile and versions (including sass gem version and gulp sass version)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your `<Ruby_installation_path>/bin` directory is in
   `PATH`environment variable. If not, append it and restart console.
2. Check compass gem is installed in Ruby. If not, run `gem install
   compass`.